# message: "Undefined variable: result"

Tags: php, postgresql

on local it can work, but on the server it's an error

controller:

```
public function postGrubdata(){
        $sql ="
            select * 
            from auth.usergroup u 
            ";

        $n = 0;
        $data = db()->raw($sql)->toArray();

        foreach($data as $v){
            $n++;

            $result['data'][] = [
                'no'             => $n,
                'id'             => $v['id'],
                'name'           => $v['name'],
                'members'        => json_decode($v['members'], TRUE),

            ];
        }
        // $result['data'] = $data;
        return $result;
    }
```

index:

```
dataTable_grub = $('table#dataTable_grub').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false,
                paging: true,
                deferRender: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{url('app/tambah_agenda/grubdata')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON"
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        // width: '1%',
                        class: 'text-center',
                        data: 'no'
                    },
                    {
                        data : 'name'
                    },
                    {
                        data:'members'
                    }
                ],
                rowCallback: function (row, data, dataIndex)
                {
                $(row).css("cursor", "pointer");
                }
            })
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have haven't defined the array `$result` in your `postGrubdata()` function.

Comment: how is it? please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

if the data is empty, then foreach does not run, so $result must be defined first

```
$result = [
        'data' => []
    ];
```

---

```
 public function postGrubdata(){
    $sql ="
        select * 
        from auth.usergroup u 
        ";


    $n = 0;
    $data = db()->raw($sql)->toArray();

    $result = [
        'data' => []
    ];
    foreach($data as $v){
        $n++;

        $result['data'][] = [
            'no'             => $n,
            'id'             => $v['id'],
            'name'           => $v['name'],
            'members'        => json_decode($v['members'], TRUE),

        ];
    }
    // $result['data'] = $data;
    return $result;
}
```